# write individual bits to a file in python

Tags: python, file, byte, bit

is there a way in python to write less than 1 byte data 
even when I write the number 0 which represented in 1 bit the file size is 1(8 bits) byte

I tried the struct module

```
file.write(struct.pack('b',0))
```

array module

```
import array
data1=array.array('B')
x=bin(0)[2:]
data1.append(int(0,2))
f2=open('/root/x.txt','wb')
data1.tofile(f2)
```

Comment: no. one byte is the minimum size of a non empty file.

Comment: I'm leaving [this link to a question about huffman encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51425638/how-to-write-huffman-coding-to-a-file-using-python#51425774) here, as OP asks about it in a comment on the accepted answer and it is a good example of how you can better leverage only being able to write bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cannot write less than a byte.  A byte is an indivisble amount of memory the computer can handle.  The hardware is  not equipped to handle units of data <1 byte (though the size of a byte may differ from machine to machine).  The file system also deals with data in units of blocks which may be 4KB, so writing one bit really results in a 4KB block on disk.

See also the more general version of this question: [It is possible to write less than 1 byte to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701221/it-is-possible-to-write-less-than-1-byte-to-a-file)

Comment: but how the Huffman encoding uses fewer bits to represent the most frequent symbols ??

Comment: @user1604573 you can transmit a series of bits, or save a series of bits into a file if you want and then interperet them however you want, but you can't write less than one byte at a time.  There's nothing stopping you from working bit-wise.  If you wanted to store something like "hello" in huffman encoding, the bits would look like this: `1010000110011100100110`, broken into bytes `10100001` `10011100` `100110`.  And you'd have two extra bits at the end.  You can get around this by indicating how many bits to read, or how many characters are in your file with a number at the very beginning.